# Использование произвольного Globals (_G)

Tags: java, lua

Внедряю скрипт в свое приложение **на Java при помощи библиотеки LuaJ**. Мне необходимо по возможности максимально вырезать лишний функционал. (В частности кроме моих функций я оставил только `type` и `pairs`) Ручками обнулять функции - то еще удовольствие. Если создать самому объект, то в нем нет нужных элементов для работы. (как минимум finder)

Можно ли создать пустой, но с необходимыми для выполнения связями `Globals` или простой способ обнулить содержимое всех его ключей?

Comment: `setfenv,` `lua_setfenv` (Lua 5.1) http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes

Comment: И `_ENV`(переменная, таблица) с версии 5.2.

Comment: Вопрос именно про библиотеку LuaJ (подправил вопрос). Т.к. мне нужно исключить какую либо возможность выходить за рамки заданного функционала и сделать это на уровне среды выполнения (Java приложения).